# Simple jQuery function doesn't work on input elements after being created

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

When I click a button I create some input elements inside a hidden div. This div becomes visible showing those elements.

```html
<div id="copiasdoc" style="display:none;"></div>
<button type="button" id="appear">click</button>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.0.min.js"></script>
<script>
  var copies = "";
  $("#appear").click(function() {
    copies+='<input type="text" class="form-control ccert" style="width:80px;display:inline-block;"><input type="text" class="form-control ccert" style="width:80px;display:inline-block;"><input type="text" class="form-control ccert" style="width:80px;display:inline-block;">';
    $("#copiasdoc").show();
    document.getElementById('copiasdoc').innerHTML += copies;
  });
  $("#copiasdoc .ccert").keyup(function () {
    alert("Hello");
  });
</script>
```

I want to get the sum of those values while typing but this doesn't work. I changed the code to make a simple task (above) like show an alert while keyup in any element but this still doesn't work.

I would like some help.

Comment: If you are dinamycally creating your elements chage your click event to `$(document).on('click', '#appear', function(){});`

Comment: @inarilo That's not right. It's simply because the elements have no events attached to them since they were created after the script ran once.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Short answer

```
$("#copiasdoc .ccert").keyup(function () {
    alert("Hello");
});
```

Should be:

```
$("#copiasdoc").on('keyup','.ccert',function () {
    alert("Hello");
}));
```

---

### Explanation

The `.on` jQuery function binds events on elements created after the `DOMReady` event is fired.

Beforehand, your newly created elements wouldn't get the event binded to them. With `.on`, they do if you specificly bind the event handler to a static parent (in this case, `#copiasdoc`).
[jQuery `.on()` API Documentation](http://api.jquery.com/on/).

### Working example

```js
   var copies = "";
   $("#appear").click(function(){
    copies+='<input type="text" class="form-control ccert" style="width:80px;display:inline-block;"><input type="text" class="form-control ccert" style="width:80px;display:inline-block;"><input type="text" class="form-control ccert" style="width:80px;display:inline-block;">';
    $("#copiasdoc").show();
    document.getElementById('copiasdoc').innerHTML += copies;
   });

   $("#copiasdoc").on('keyup','.ccert',(function () {
    alert("Hello");
   }));
```

```html
<div id="copiasdoc" style="display:none;"></div>
  <button type="button" id="appear">click</button>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.0.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Not to nitpick, as you did answer OPs question, but your explanation is not correct. The difference between your .on  and their .keyup is that you used event delegation. on does not inherently fix their problem, it’s the fact that you are binding the handler to a static parent element (#copiasdoc) and instructing jquery to only act on  captured child nodes (event.target) that have the .ccert class, which will include dynamically added nodes

Comment: @RobM. Thank you for correcting me. I will update my explanation accordingly. Also, thank you for taking to time to detail what is going on in a `.on()` event when a parent element is specified in the parameters !

Answer (score 2):

You current event handler binds to a static set of elements (the ones that exist when it is run the first time). If you want the handler to apply to dynamically created elements, you should use event delegation:

```
$("#copiasdoc").on('keyup', '.ccert', function () {
    alert("Hello");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

since you are adding elements dynamically, you need to use event delegation, you can use `$(document).on('keyup', "#copiasdoc .ccert", function () {})`, something like this:

```html
<div id="copiasdoc" style="display:none;"></div>
  <button type="button" id="appear">click</button>



<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.0.min.js"></script>
  <script>
   var copies = "";
   $("#appear").click(function(){
    copies+='<input type="text" class="form-control ccert" style="width:80px;display:inline-block;"><input type="text" class="form-control ccert" style="width:80px;display:inline-block;"><input type="text" class="form-control ccert" style="width:80px;display:inline-block;">';
    $("#copiasdoc").show();
    document.getElementById('copiasdoc').innerHTML += copies;
   });

   $(document).on('keyup', "#copiasdoc .ccert", function () {
    alert("Hello");
   });
  </script>
```